# Access child element of a component from a parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a `Form` component which renders 3 `InputContainer` components. I want to access the value of the `input` element on the `submit` event of the form. Right now, my `submitResource` function logs the `div` which contains both `label` and `input` element.

If not necessary, I don't want to emit any events with @change handler. The only way I've managed to access the `input` element is by `console.log(titleRef.value.$el.querySelector('input'));` but I think its not the right way to do it.

Thank you!

`Form.vue`

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitResource">
    <InputContainer ref="titleRef" />
    <InputContainer ref="descriptionRef"/>
    <InputContainer ref="linkRef" />
    <BaseButton type="submit" class="submit">Add Resource</BaseButton>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
import BaseButton from './BaseButton.vue';
import InputContainer from './InputContainer.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const titleRef = ref(null);
const descriptionRef = ref(null);
const linkRef = ref(null);

const submitResource = () => {
  console.log(titleRef.value.$el);
};
</script>
```

`InputContainer.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="example">Example</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="example"
      name="example"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use emits/listeners? If you don't like how data flows through ViemModel frameworks like Vue/Angular/React, you might be better off using pure JQuery.

Comment: I actually got it working using the @change and emitting the event to the parent component, but was curious if I could do it in another way which looked easier.

Comment: Typically, you'd use `@update:modelValue` instead of `@change` so that you can use two way binding with [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defineExpose` to forward a ref from the child.

InputContainer.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="example">Example</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="example"
      ref="inputRef"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const inputRef = ref(null);
defineExpose({
    inputRef
});
</script>
```

Then, you can access it in `Form.vue`.

```js
const submitResource = () => {
  const titleInputEl = titleRef.value.inputRef;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, the typical way to do this in Vue is through two-way binding with `v-model`. For this to work, you build your input components to receive a value through the `:modelValue` prop and have them emit an `@update:modelValue` event:

`Form.vue`

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitResource">
    <InputContainer v-model="formData.title" />
    <InputContainer v-model="formData.description"/>
    <InputContainer v-model="formData.link" />
    <BaseButton type="submit" class="submit">Add Resource</BaseButton>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
import BaseButton from './BaseButton.vue';
import InputContainer from './InputContainer.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const formData = ref({
  title: '',
  description: '',
  link: '',
});

const submitResource = () => {
  console.log(formData.value);
};
</script>
```

`InputContainer.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="example">Example</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="example"
      :value="modelValue"
      @input="emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

This approach has several benefits, among them is:

- loose coupling: parent does not need to know about internal structure of child
- single source of reference: all data is represented in the data layer and reliably up to date (instead of floating around in the template) - this allows for efficient validation, debugging, etc.
- readability: binding is apparent in the template instead of buried somewhere in the code
- portability: pretty much all Vue components use this format, you can easily replace other input components with yours and vice versa
- no surprises: if other developers work with your code, this is what they'll expect

Comment: This is most definitely helpful! I already accepted an answer to the original question, but thanks a lot for your input Moritz.